# Get the line number of file

Tags: c, file, io

I am reading a file, and want to store the line number on a particular condition.

I know that `fgets`used to read the line, is there any way to store/get the line number where the cursor located.

Comment: What do you mean by *cursor* ? If it's file pointer, using line counter when you read with `fgets()` is enough?

Comment: suppose, `if(strncmp(ioarea,"ABC",3)==0)` on this condition i want to store the line number. counter gives me the count of "ABC" in a file but not the line number of "ABC"

Comment: on each fgets() increment a counter (that started at 0) then check the condition.  if condition true, then save line number.

Comment: you could also, when the condition is true, use ftell() to get the actual number of bytes to the NEXT line in the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no cursor in the context of a standard file stream. There is a file pointer, but not a cursor. The cursor is a concept of the console / terminal driver. Even with file pointers, you don't typically use them in line-mode, they are for random access / binary type access. You can seek to the beginning and end of a file in text mode. But fseek isn't "line or cursor" aware so don't use it.

You simply need to track the number of lines you've read with an integer.

```
int line = 0;
while((fgets(...)) != NULL) {
    line++;
    ...
    if(...) {
        // store line number wherever you need it
        printf("found at line %d\n", line);    
    }
}
```